# How to make my 2D character 'look' or flip in the direction he is moving?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm a total newbie in Unity and I'm learning/making my first game, which will be a platformer. I want to get the movement perfect first. I've added a simple script that enables the player to move and jump.

Here it is:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour{
    public float jumpspeed = 5f;
    public float speed = 5f;
    Rigidbody2D rb;
    GameObject character;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    void Awake(){
        rb = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)){
            Jump();
        }
        Vector3 move = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0f, 0f);
        transform.position += move *Time.deltaTime * speed;
    }
    void Jump(){
        rb.AddForce(new Vector2(0f, jumpspeed), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }
}
```

Now, I want the character to face in the direction in which it moves. The png is facing to the right by default.
[image]

How can I do that? Also, can I make my movement script better?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would try something like `transform.localScale.x *= -1`. Assuming that the object has a reasonable origin.

Answer (score 1):

I typically do this using code like this based off a bool.

```
void FlipSprite()
{
    isFacingRight = !isFacingRight;

    Vector3 theScale = transform.localScale;
    theScale.x *= -1;
    transform.localScale = theScale;
}
```

Comment: So this function will be called in the void Update()?

Comment: It's giving an error: The name 'isFacingRight' does not exist in the current context

Comment: you have to create the bool outside the function. and this function is called under the circumstances in which you change direction. Depends on the value of the horizontal axis

Comment: I generally agree with this solution. I would, however, try to avoid having the same information in two separate variables. Otherwise, this just increases the chance to forget one of the two when doing something down the road. An alternative would be to make `IsFacingRight` a property that internally modifies the scale.